# Child element not positioned correctly relative to parent element?

Tags: html, css

I have code blocks on my website that look like this:

[image]

This pre block has a child button, as shown below.

[image]

I am applying the following CSS to the button element:

```
pre[class*="language-"] button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;

    font-size: 0.9rem;
    padding: 0.15rem;
    border: ridge 1px #7b7b7c;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-shadow: #c4c4c4 0 0 2px;
}

code[class*="language-"] button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #bcbabb;
}
```

However, the button appears to be located `top: 5px; right: 5px;` *of the HTML document* instead of the pre (ignore the toggle).

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M1C2.png)

I removed the positioning from the button, and it now appears *kinda* correctly (at least somewhat in the right place) like so:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwc2L.png)

I can't figure it out why the CSS isn't correctly positioning it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `absolute`
> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to its *closest [positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#types_of_positioning) ancestor*, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is determined by the values of `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left`.

[MDN - CSS - Position - Absolute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute)

Add `position:relative` to `pre` so that the button can be absolutely positioned inside the `pre`

```css
pre[class*="language-"] button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding: 0.15rem;
  border: ridge 1px #7b7b7c;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-shadow: #c4c4c4 0 0 2px;
}

code[class*="language-"] button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #bcbabb;
}

pre {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<pre class="language-js">
  <code class="language-js">
    some code
  </code>
  <button>Copy</button>
</pre>
```

Comment: Yup this, when using absolute position on an element it's parent needs to have postion:relative or else the position is absolute relative to the overall page.

Comment: That's great and now the positioning works - however it seems to be positioning it compared to a line of text?

It is better explained visually:

[Image](https://imgur.com/a/iqYLA6E)